# WebView CanGoBack is not working inside TabHost

Tags: android, android-webview, android-tabhost

I have created the Dynamic Tabhost using the following link

http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1132

I have changed the Content with WebView as below

```
ts3.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
             public View createTabContent(String tag)
             {
                LinearLayout panel = new LinearLayout(sActiveContext);
                panel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                panel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                WebView webview=new WebView(sActiveContext);                
                panel.addView(webview);
                return panel;
             }
        });
```

webview.goback() is implemented as below

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {          
             if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
               {
                   switch(keyCode)
                   {
                      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:   

                       if(webview.canGoBack())
                           webview.goBack();
                       else
                           //alert                     
                           return true;
                   }

               }
               return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

`always i'm getting alert msg only`. What i missed?

**Note: Number of tabs and titles passed from client side. The above code are in server side.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this goback issue with WebView. I have taken the current webview from the current tab of tabhost. Now working fine

```
public static WebView getCurrentWebView()
  {
     if(sTabHost!=null)
          {
      View view=sTabHost.getCurrentView();
            if(view!=null)
            {
             View child=((ViewGroup)view).getChildAt(0);
             for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)child).getChildCount(); i++) {
               View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)child).getChildAt(i);
               if(nextChild!=null)
               {
                String type=nextChild.getClass().toString();
                if(type!=null && !type.equals("") && type.equals("class android.webkit.WebView"))
                {
                 sCurrentWebView=(WebView) (((ViewGroup)child).getChildAt(i));                  
                 break;
                }                 
               }
           }
            }           
          }
     return sCurrentWebView;
  }

@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {          
             if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
               {
                   switch(keyCode)
                   {
                      case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:   
                       WebView view=getCurrentWebView();
                       if(view!=null && view.canGoBack())
                         view.goBack();
                       else
                           //alert                     
                           return true;
                   }

               }
               return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```